# How to use same complex type as a property of several output types but different source types

Tags: automapper

I have a class for CountryAndCity:

```
public class CountryAndCity
{

    public Country Country { get; set; }

    public City City { get; set; }

    public ZipCode ZipCode { get; set; }

}
```

I am using this class in several output classes, for example:

```
public class OutputClassA
{
    public CountryAndCity CountryAndCity { get; set; }
}

public class OutputClassB
{
    public CountryAndCity CountryAndCity { get; set; }
}
```

In addition, i have some "Input Classes" which includes the same relevant fields for mapping with additional other fields:

```
public class InputClassA : ICountryAndCity
{
    ...Some other properties.....

    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryDesc { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityDesc { get; set; }

    ...Some other properties.....
}

public class InputClassB : ICountryAndCity
{
    ...Some other properties.....

    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryDesc { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityDesc { get; set; }

    ...Some other properties.....
}
```

i didn't want to duplicate the code for every CreateMap statement for CountryAndCity property mapping for every Input and output combination types so i decided to use an interface that all the "input types" implements.

i created this configuration and its working great if i implement ICountryAndCity on all the relevant "input classes" and using "Mapper.Map" for the interface inside the CreateMap function.

```
     Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {

         cfg.CreateMap<InputClassA, OutputClassA>()
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryAndCity,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<ICountryAndCity, CountryAndCity>((ICountryAndCity)src)));           

         cfg.CreateMap<InputClassB, OutputClassB>()
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryAndCity,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<ICountryAndCity, CountryAndCity>((ICountryAndCity)src)));           



         cfg.CreateMap<ICountryAndCity, CountryAndCity>()
                     .ForMember(dest => dest.Country,
                        opts => opts.MapFrom(
                           src => new Country
                           {
                               CountryId = src.CountryId,
                               CountryDesc = src.CountryDesc
                           }))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.City,
                        opts => opts.MapFrom(
                           src => new City
                           {
                               CityId = src.CityId,
                               CityDesc = src.CityDesc
                           }))
                        .ForMember(dest => dest.ZipCode,
                        opts => opts.MapFrom(
                           src => new ZipCode
                           {
                               ZipCodeId = src.ZipCodeId,
                               ZipCodeDesc = src.ZipCodeDesc
                           }));
    }
```

I am sure that there is other better way to do it using AutoMapper without using interface. Can someone help with that?

Comment: You can try to use the [default flattening](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Flattening.html) with [unflattening](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu will it work for MultiLevel types? its not seems to work in my scenario... can you please help with an example?

Comment: It works with multiple levels too. The docs already have examples.

Comment: You own solution can be improved with Include. See [here](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu i think that it will work only when i am using specific naming convention for the properties. Customer (CustomerName, CustomerId, etc..) isn't it? i have different naming convention...

Comment: By default yes, but you can customize the naming convention. I'm not saying that solution is better. The Include way is certainly more obvious, but it has more ceremony.